# Legal responsibility of a university for international students (Europe)

Tags: europe, legal-issues, international-students, tuition

I am a non-EU student in a European university that has international master and doctoral programs for foreign students.
I have found the university does not offer important forms in English that would also benefit international students (e.g., tuition fee reimbursement application form that describes various contexts sufficing such application). I wonder if there is any legal document describing responsibilities or duties of universities having international students.

Comment: If the country is not an English speaking one, it is likely that any legal documents will be in the official language (or languages), whatever they might be. If they have an international students office/association, likely they can help.

Comment: It's quite possible that such laws would vary from country to country, if any exist.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster for your comments. It is an Austrian university. I wonder your thoughts on the context, they might help guiding me. I missed the opportunity of the application due to my lack of German skills. Do you think international students have a right to demand such forms to be also in English? They do inform the deadline to pay tuition fee in English as well.

Comment: I meant the above message for you too, @Wetenschaap.

Comment: You can demand, but there likely is no legal requirement. Living in Austria is, of course, a wonderful opportunity to learn German.

Comment: It baffles me again and again how people (academics!) first relocate to a foreign country without a base knowledge of the language and then don't try to learn it as fast as possible.

Comment: What language is the program conducted in? Does your university have an international office? I have seen instances where all official documentation was in German, but human assistance was provided to non-speakers for tasks such as filling out forms. And any reason why you cannot translate the forms yourself, using online tools?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I'm a PhD student, all lectures I attended and the communication within the university was in English. The university does not have a designated international office. Filling out the form would not have been a problem (using online translation even by typing), but I simply did not know the option I could have used for the reimbursement or waiver of the tuition fee. If I did not look up the form somehow, I would not have known it at all.

Comment: I completely doubt students have a *right* to this form in English.  It would immediately be perceived as another example of English imperialism.  I would think that your department is aware of such forms and would make you aware of them.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, unfortunately not. My institute did not concern this kind of 'personal' matter at all. I just conclude that my university which does not have many non-EU students do not feel that they need to provide such information as the guideline (in my answer below) says.

Comment: @Karl and who thought the comment was useful, I have tried to learn it. It saddens me again and again how some people just put their personal frustration as comments without any constructive information or empathetic consideration.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no legal basis, yet something similar could be found, sort of Code of Conduct originating from the website of Die Österreichische Universitätenkonferenz https://uniko.ac.at/index.php?lang=DE.
My university would be the example of a university that follows the guideline poorly.
For the whole document, please search *GUIDELINES for Academic Studies of International Students at Austrian Universities*.

[image: The 1st page of GUIDELINES for Academic Studies of International Students at Austrian Universities]

[image: A part of the 2nd page of GUIDELINES for Academic Studies of International Students at Austrian Universities]
[image: A part of the 4th page of GUIDELINES for Academic Studies of International Students at Austrian Universities]

Comment: "Preferably" means just that...preferably.

Comment: @BryanKrause, of course I know that. ;) I guess that's why they actively inform also in English for the need to pay the tuition fee. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯